# Visual Studio Code debugger not working and error on project load

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Studio Code and the C# extension. It worked fine until today. When I start the program I get this error.

> Attempted to update project that is not loaded: e:\folder with
>   files\vsc\C#\P2\P2.csproj.

When I press F5 to debug my code I get in the terminal:

> the prelaunchtask build terminated with exit code 1"and "MSBUILD :
>   error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working
>   directory does not contain a project or solution file. The terminal
>   process terminated with exit code: 1

I tried the Code Runner extension and it works with Python, but no luck with C#.

What is happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: It looks like it is trying to load a .csproj (C# project file) but you claim that there is not one. What file are you trying to load?

Comment: I used "dotnet new console" and that made both a .csproj file and .cs file. I just tested it and "dotnet run" works, but F5 and ctrl + F5 does not. @ZachPedigo

Comment: @ZachPedigo After some more messing around I found that it is simply not seeing the .csproj file. I have the exact same extension and version on my laptop and it is working. Should I just uninstall everything and reinstall?

Comment: You could do that and see if it works, but do you actually have the.csproj file or just the .cs file? If it really is not seeing the .csproj file then you may be missing some required components for the editor to open the project or there could be a bug in the editor's software.